# Multi Language WordPress website with 2 installs advice

Tags: php, html, wordpress, multilingual, multiple-instances

I have a potential client who wants a HTML website migrated to WordPress, the current website is 100 pages; 50 English and 50 French of the same content. There are several reasons for moving to WordPress, and having an English and French version of the same site instead of just a translator plugin. So enough back story, my real questions is...

How do I deal with running 2 Wordpress websites (one English the other French) when a visitor wants to change a specific page from English to French for example? and avoid going back to the home page when requesting to change language?

If a visitor is viewing a specific page in English but wants to view it in French, I do not want the Language selection button to take them to the home page really. How can I do this in WordPress; with 2 separate installs so when you click the language button the page just changes to the requested language?

I hope someone can help me, Thank you.

Luke

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need to make 2 separate websites . Just use [qTranslate](http://wordpress.org/plugins/qtranslate/).

It is hands down the best solution for multilingual wordpress installation, and I myself have used it with over 100 multilingual sites

The management and maintenance would be much easier , you will have a control over all aspects of the multilingual behavior and you could SHARE resources ( like scripts, images , themes etc ) .

With this plugin you can choose if you want to have a URL like :

- `http://www.mysite.com/fr` and `http://www.mysite.com/en`
- `http://fr.mysite.com` and `http://en.mysite.com`
- `http://www.mysite.com/?lang=fr` and `http://www.mysite.com/?lang=en`

All your users will see is a small flags based or menu based language switcher .

The Admin screens easily share languages , switching, and content handling . Even switching the admin area language itself is a breeze .

You even have control over local SEO.

Every aspect from title to media to custom fields is also supported . Basically you have duplicate fields for title content etc . The best way to understand is just install one time and start to use .

you will get the idea in a second .

It has a very extensive hooks base and custom functions that allow you to easily do virtually everything !

Example of a working ( old ) wp install with qTranslate supporting 5 languages can be found [here](http://www.summerconf.com)

P.s.

I am in no way affiliated with the author of this totally free plugin - But I do admire the work he has made and the techniques used in his code . If you end up using it - a small token of appreciation for the author would surely be appreciated by him .

**Edit I** after comment.

Grammar or the correctness of the translation is irrelevant .

> qtranslate is **not** an automated translation service / plugin

It does not really translate your site , but gives you the tools to do so in terms of UI, accessibility, functions and hooks.

The actual content is translated by YOU. No automatic content generation ( unless you specifically want one )

It actually does create 2 different websites ( in a sense ) but using the same install, core files, resources etc ..

Until you will not try and use it , you will not fully understand how it works.

Comment: The main reason I need 2 separate websites is for the English and French SEO, plus all of the content is already translated correctly. with correct grammar.

Comment: @LukeD1uk Grammer has nothing to do with it . This is not automatic translation service . If you will try that plugin, you will understand you do NOT need two separate websites to have the exact same result . Take it from one who has a LOT of experience in multilingual websites . and check the posted example as well to see for yourself . I made websites with up to 15 languages with that plugin.

Comment: This has been discussed here: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/21454/open-source-replacement-for-wpml and here: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/7242/best-wordpress-localization-plugin 
Personally I'm not a big fan of qTranslate, because it copies all translations into one blog post. If you wanna switch to a different plugin later, it will be difficult.

Comment: @Remy - I do not see any problem in changing plugin ( and also - why would anyone do that ?? ) . Having 6 different sites for 6 languages is just wrong . there is absolutely no logic excuse of doing that . But to each its own . I got nothing against those who want to learn the hard way .. – And BTW - At the topics you have included also qTranslate gets the highest voting. I guess simply because it is the best one . By far.

Comment: @ObmerkKronen Ok, but why would I use this over WPML? I am reading that's very good also.

Comment: @LukeD1uk. Hi. Use whatever you want . I am just speaking of my vast experience with multi language websites and I am just recommending . the choice is yours. I also do not understand what the problem is - take half an hour, install both, inspect, valuate, and decide . WPML is not free ( not as beer and not as freedom ). qTranslate is. and it also supply a huge array of hooks ( for coders ). But I will reiterate - it is a bit of a useless conversation. Just give them both a try and see. ( or just use WPML or double WP install or triple or network ) . Whatever works for you.

Comment: I'm just mentioning that if you use qTranslate you cannot switch to a different plugin later cause it stores all translations into the same blogpost. Others create individual blogposts. If you never want to switch, then it's perfect. http://wordpress.org/plugins/multilingual-press/ supports Multisite installations.

Comment: @Remy this is turning into a real discussion board, but : `1` - qTranslate also works on Multisite ( been there, done that ). `2` - since it uses a special known syntax, and also supply hooks and functions, getting only ONE language ( meaning - separating the content as per your unlikely scenario ) is hard only if someone does not know how to use a PHP function on it´s own. otherwise it is 2-3 lines of code . But again ( and hopefully last time ) Why not just `TRY` and decide instead of discussing about it ? testing all of the pssible methods / plugins mentioned here is 1 hour tops.

Comment: @ObmerkKronen Thank you very much for your comments, it has been very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

[Wordpress Multisite Language Switcher](http://wordpress.org/plugins/multisite-language-switcher/) is the way to go.

- Every language version gets its own Wordpress blog
- You get a "Network Root" where admin tasks spanning all two blogs are done
- Posts/pages can be associated between the two language sites

This is like Wordpress.com hosted blogs.

I use this plugin on a blog successfuly. I worried about routing some time: which URL should be canonical? `foo.com/bar` or `foo.com/en/bar`? This became an issue when my client wanted to install a separate .de domain instead of using the virtual sub folder `/de/`

Comment: So you have 2 seperate wordpress websites? and this plugin creates a link between the matching posts and pages that match?

Comment: what is the point of seperating the content like that ? and of a much more complicated `network` installation ? It is really not a good set up for maintenance and administration ..

Comment: The point is I need English and French SEO, plus the content is already translated and in this format already.

Comment: LukeD1uk, you're right, that's essentially how it works. @krembo99 has a point, though:  it's an effort to create the links. It's less of a pain if the pages don't change a lot -- but if you, for example, run 2 blogs in parallel, this is going to get on your nerves. I'd prefer extending a post object to contain 2 language contents.